# Sucuri alerts advising WordPress posts have been updated by unauthorised party

Tags: wordpress

I have the Sucuri plugin on a WordPress site I've had for a while and receive daily alerts such as -

Message: Nf_sub status has been changed; details: ID: 2261,Old status: new,New status: publish,Title:

The alerts include details of the IP being used but I don't know what posts are being updated as there is nothing obvious and there have been no actual logins to the site. I'm also using WordFence which doesn't indicate any problems.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction to resolving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for programming-specific questions. Questions about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  However please review their help section first before posting to make sure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I had this alert today and found out that it coincided with someone sending a message via the contact form (I use Ninja Forms). I guess Nf_sub = Ninja Form submission.